# Angular - Form Validation - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so I have a form with an input and some other stuff and I'm trying to do some angular validation to make sure that the entered information is actually there (not blank). To do so, I'm using an `if` statement.

The error message I get is:

`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

It seems as if it can't read an `<input>` tag name if it's left blank. The function works when I fill in the , but not the others (which are a  and . I'm just trying to use an `if` statement to see if they've been filled out. Here's the html and angular code below:

`reviewModal.view.html (shortened form version)`

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div role="alert" ng-show="vm.formError" class="alert alert-danger">{{ vm.formError }}</div>
    <form id="addReview" name="addReview" role="form" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal">
        <label for"name" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
                <input id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.formData.name" class="form-control">
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit review</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

`reviewModal.controller.js`

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('loc8rApp')
        .controller('reviewModalCtrl', reviewModalCtrl);

    reviewModalCtrl.$inject = ['$uibModalInstance', 'locationData'];
    function reviewModalCtrl($uibModalInstance, locationData) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.locationData = locationData;

        vm.onSubmit = function() {
            vm.formError = "";
            if(!vm.formData.name || !vm.formData.rating || !vm.formData.reviewText) {
                vm.formError = "All fields required, please try again";
                return false;
            } else {
                console.log(vm.formData);
                return false;
            }

        };

        vm.modal = {
            cancel : function() {
                $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
            }
        };
    }

})();
```

`locationDetail.controller.js`

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('loc8rApp')
        .controller('locationDetailCtrl', locationDetailCtrl);

    locationDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams', '$uibModal', 'loc8rData'];
    function locationDetailCtrl($routeParams, $uibModal, loc8rData) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.locationid = $routeParams.locationid;

        loc8rData.locationById(vm.locationid)
            .success(function(data) {
                vm.data = { location: data };
                vm.pageHeader = {
                    title: vm.data.location.name
                };
            })
            .error(function(e) {
                console.log(e);
            });

        vm.popupReviewForm = function() {
            var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: '/reviewModal/reviewModal.view.html',
                controller: 'reviewModalCtrl as vm',
                resolve : {
                    locationData : function() {
                        return {
                            locationid : vm.locationid,
                            locationName : vm.data.location.name
                        };
                    }
                }
            });
        };

    }

})();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

vm.formData must be defined before you can assigned/read name property in the html. Update code in reviewModalCtrl to init vm.formData:

```
vm.formData = {};
```

Comment: Well, it works in one manner, but now if I fill out all the form fields and submit, it still gives me an error. I think that initiating it overwrites data from the form fields.

Comment: So yes, you were right, but the trick was to initiate it outside of the `vm.onSubmit` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use angular validation instated validating things in controller as follows.

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div role="alert" ng-show="addReview.$submitted && addReview.$invalid" class="alert alert-danger">All fields required, please try again</div>
    <form id="addReview" name="addReview" role="form" ng-submit="vm.onSubmit()" class="form-horizontal">
        <label for"name" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
                <input id="name" name="name" ng-model="vm.formData.name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit review</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I have used **`required`** in text box and show the error message on top with
**`ng-show="addReview.$invalid"`**

You do not need any code on controller.

Comment: Thanks, Partha, this is probably a much better solution to validation, but one point is that I need to grab and use the form data in angular, so I still need to be able to read the `vm.formData.name`. And so even a simple `if(!vm.formData.name ... )` doesn't seem to be grabbing the data from the front end.

Comment: Before cheking the `fromData.name` please check `fromData` first as `if (!vm.fromData && !vm.formData.name)..` also do not forget to initialize as Vu Quyet's answer.